# AngularJS Return object of methods after IndexedDB call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I need to return an object of methods after making a call to the IndexedDB library like so.

```
.factory('presentationData', ['$indexedDB', 'uuid4','$q', function ($indexedDB, uuid4, $q) {

  var objectStore = $indexedDB.openStore('presentations', function(store) {
    return store;
  });

  return objectStore.then(function(objectStore) {
    var functions = getDefaultDataServiceFunctions(objectStore);

    functions.getAll = function (includeFlaggedForDelete) {
      if (includeFlaggedForDelete) {
        return objectStore.getAll();
      }
      return objectStore.getAll().then(function (presentations) {
        return presentations.filter(function (p) {
          return !(p.meta && p.meta.localStatus === 'deleted');
        });
      });
    };

    functions.getWithLocalStatus = function (status) {
      var query = $indexedDB.queryBuilder().$index('localStatus').$eq(status).compile();
      return objectStore.each(query);
    };

    return functions;
  })
}])
```

Why does this not return an object of methods? I don't understand!!

Using this: https://github.com/bramski/angular-indexedDB

Thanks!

Comment: if you can reproduce it in jsfiddle, it will help resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work as returning the store object is ineffective.  The store will be closed and operations on it will fail.

It's really unclear to me what you are actually trying to do.  Just get the data?  You need to return a promise which will return the data.

```
.service('dataFetcher', ['$indexedDB', 'uuid4','$q', function ($indexedDB, uuid4, $q) {
  this.getData = function() {
    promise = $q.defer();
    $indexedDB.openStore('presentations', function (store) {
      ... do what is needed to get the answer here...
      promise.resolve(data);
    }
    return promise.promise;
  }
}
```

Using this service then goes something like...

```
.controller('MyControl', ['dataFetcher', function ($scope, dataFetcher) {
  dataFetcher.getData().then( function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
  });
}];
```

That will give you what you in fact seek.  indexed-DB works on a callback mechanism.  You need to use that to design your data service in a sensible way.